# Laravel Cashier/Stripe not setting subscription_ends_at

Tags: laravel

Laravel Cashier is not setting the subscription_ends_at field when i create a new subscription. I´ve been fiddling arround with this now a few days, and i think that at the very beginning it worked, but i had to pull the repository we´re working on again and lost the changes and i did install and configure everything again, now it won´t set that field. It sets, though, the trial_ends_at if i specify a trial period.

It´s a yearly plan and we would like to inform our users of the renewal date.

The user model:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

use Laravel\Cashier\BillableTrait;
use Laravel\Cashier\BillableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface, BillableInterface {


    use BillableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';


    protected $dates = ['trial_ends_at', 'subscription_ends_at'];
```

The controller method for creating the subscription:

```
public function postConfirmSubscription()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->subscription('premium')->create(Input::get('token.id'));
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8):

Laravel Cashier will NOT set the subscription_ends_at field, unless that subscription is cancelled. It is designed to manage grace periods (user will have access until that date, once the subscription is cancelled), not to inform the user about their next payment date, or remaining active subscription time. As I originally thought too.

You may have actually seen that field populated, when you were testing the cancel procedure.

I'm affraid you'll have to set up an extra field for that, let's say "next_payment_at", and "manually" update it, either at controller or model level.